# How do I output a 64bit number on Arduino if its libraries have 32 bit restrictions?

Tags: c, algorithm, serialization, arduino, bit-manipulation

The compiler provided for Arduino seems to generate code that can work with 64 bit numbers, but the I/O classes, for instance `Serial.Print()`, seem to not work beyond 32 bit numbers.

How can I overcome these limitations and print all possible 64 bit unsigned integers as decimal numbers?

A bit of background:

For an Arduino project I need to send a number on Serial that fits on a uint64_t variable type, but for some reason the Arduino Serial port can't handle a type bigger than 32 bit (but the device supports a 6-bit type).

Thus, I need to print that (64-bit) number as Decimal on Serial port only. To do this I was thinking of dividing the number in two blocks of 32 bit each with a bitwise operation. Then send each number in sequence on the Serial port, but obviously the resulting number is different from the original 64-bit number.

For example, I use an unsigned 8-bit number as follows:

```
11100010 <- 226 in Decimal
```

And I need to send it to my serial port, but it can only handle 4-bit numbers at max.

Thus I try to split the number in two parts with a bitwise mask:

```
1110 <- MSBs (14 in Decimal)
0010 <- LSBs (2 in Decimal)
```

So when I send it in sequence on the Serial I see a 142, but instead what I would is 226.

So, is there an algorithm that given a number as input, the returned result are two numbers that are the breakdown of the previous binary number in MSBs and LSBs?

Appendix:

I'm using streaming.h for serial communication.

---

As properly guessed by @Infixed I'm trying to:

> How do I print a 64 bit number in decimal given 32 bit integer
>   limitations on formatted decimal output?

And up to now I found:

```
uint64_t val;
uint32_t MSBval, LSBval;
MSBval = (uint32_t)(val / 10000000000LL);
LSBval = (uint32_t)(val % 10000000000LL);
Serial << F("[") << MSBval << LSBval << F("]") << endl;
```

As you can see I have not yet found the right solution. For higher numbers the formula should not work correctly, but for some reason (I'm still trying to figure out why) when I send the result on the Serial it returns the right number even with the highest number (255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 [18446744073709551615]).

---

Check the accepted answer for more solutions that do not relies on Streaming.h library.

---

**THE SOLUTION**

This solution is not very elegant, but at least works well for my purpose.
If desired, it can be generalized to be used with all types of integers (depends on your Arduino board microcontroller type).

For now is tested only with `uint64_t` on Arduino Uno R3 (ATmega328P).

Since it seems to be the only complete solution to solve this kind of problem that I was able to find on the web then, if anyone finds any bugs or like to improve it, feel free to reply to (or edit) this post.

Here's the code:

```
uint8_t MLSBval;
uint64_t val;
char buffer[11];

//val = 18440000009000100000LL; // Test 64bit split
val = 18440000009099999999LL;   // Test 64bit split

sprintf(buffer, "%010lu", MLSBval); // Formatting zeros
Serial << F("[") << (uint32_t)(val / 10000000000LL); // Output MSBval

val = val % 10000000000LL;                         // Calculate LSBval
if (val != 0){
    MLSBval = (uint8_t)(val / 100000000LL);
    val = (val % 100000000LL);
    sprintf(buffer, "%02u", MLSBval); // Formatting zeros
    Serial << buffer;
}
sprintf(buffer, "%08lu", (uint32_t)(val));    // Formatting zeros
Serial << (buffer) << F("]") << endl;         // Data to Serial Monitor;
```

Then a little explanation:

The biggest problem lies in the length of the decimal number. If the length of the number (e.g. 99 length is 2; 1294 length is 4; etc.) is odd we need to put the `if statement` code with the `MSBval` result and then use it in the serial.

Conversely (as showed in the code), if the number is even we need to put the `if statement` code with the `LSBval` and then use the result.

This applies to all types of integers.

If you use another `int` type (32 bit, 16 bit, etc.) as a `val` type you need to change (reduce) the divider and module number in relation to the above example.

In this case the numbers of zeros of the divider and module before the `if statement` corresponds to the half the length of the largest number that fit the uint64 type (in Decimal, then ten zeroes). Instead those contained inside the `if statement` have two zeros in less (eight zeroes).

Obviously I have not tested the code with all the numbers involved, but I hope this work with all!

Comment: `i need to print that (64bit) number as Decimal on Serial port only. ` why?

Comment: You are very confused. Bits are just bits. Send any of them in any order you like, as long as the guy on the other side knows, and he can reassemble them. A serial port by definition only sends one bit at a time, though most (including the Arduino's) have an 8-bit shift register so that you can send and receive 8 bits in software. But again, which ones you send and in which order are entirely up to you.

Comment: Are you saying that `Serial.print(N)` does not work for N being a  `long long` 64 bit number?   If that is your problem, then splitting at a bit boundaries is not going to help.    That's equivalent to dividing and getting remainders of a power of 2.   To get decimal you need to think about powers of 10.  You may even be better off breaking your number into single digits and printing them one at a time.

Comment: I think he's looking for something like this: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=58697.msg422207#msg422207 but I'm not making it an answer until the question is clearer.

Comment: @infixed i don't understand at which part of the topic you linked you refers. Please give me your solution and i tell you if is what i'm searching for. thanks

Comment: Will something like this work for you?  `uint64_t n = foo(); do { send (n%10 + '0)'; n /= 10; ) while (n);`  Of course it sends the digits in reverse order, but that is easy to fix.

Comment: @Lashane for check some eeproms data with the serial monitor on Arduino IDE

Comment: The question is well-stated given an arduino context, and quite clear to those who are familiar with the arduino world. For folks who arrive here having the same issue: ignore all the comments, as they reflect a deep misunderstanding of the issue. The accepted answer is correct and solves the problem as a workaround for most cases.  Those who maintain the Arduino print libraries are well aware of this problem, but chose not to include support for printing 64 bit numbers because it makes sketches much, much larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question really depends on what is receiving the data being sent by the Serial class.

If it's human eyes reading, then you apparently are looking to actually print a decimal number.

If you are trying to pass it to another program who will reassemble two or more messages into a 64bit number, that's a different problem.

But if it's for a human to read, from the arduino forums comes this example sketch on how to print a `long long`

```
long long x = 999999999999LL;  // note the double LL

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("I am Arduino");
  char buffer[100];
  sprintf(buffer, "%0ld", x/1000000L);
  Serial.print(buffer); 
  sprintf(buffer, "%0ld", x%1000000L);
  Serial.println(buffer); 
}

void loop() {}
```

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=58697.msg422207#msg422207

EDIT
The observation in the comments that the modulus of 1,000,000,000 (a billion) can be used instead of 1,000,000 (a million) to allow a larger range is correct. But since an unsigned 64 bit number can represent up to 18446744073709551615, that is still more than 18 times a billion squared.   So even a modulus of a billion isn't perfect, After dividing by a billion, the result will not fit into a 32 bit integer.  A billion billion can fit into a 60 bit number

[ACADEMIC ANNEX because the question does not seem to be coming off hold ]

Three ways it can be done, geared more to look how, rather than optimized
The third one is probably good enough to be a real answer

```
// Here is the totally unoptimized version to help you understand
// the low level of what needs to be done.   Lots of leading zeros
// because its easier that way.
// no one would do it this way except to learn the basic idea
void PrintNumberV1(unsigned long long num)
{
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num / 10000000000000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /  1000000000000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /   100000000000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /    10000000000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /     1000000000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /      100000000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /       10000000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /        1000000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /         100000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /          10000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /           1000000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /            100000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /             10000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /              1000000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /               100000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /                10000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /                 1000LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /                  100LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /                   10LL) % 10));
    Serial.print((unsigned)((num /                    1LL) % 10));
}

// This is the way they'll show you in CompSci 101 when they want to
// to teach you about recursion, neglecting to mention how much stack
// and time it takes.  No leading zeros, because it's easier that way
void PrintNumberV2(unsigned long long num)
{
    int digit = num % 10;

    // do any more significant digits
    if (num > 9) PrintNumberV2(num / 10);

    // Print the digit this level of recursion has decided on
    Serial.print(digit);
}

// The way a C programmer might do it if he didn't have printf right there
// For extra fun you can use any base between 2 and 16
// No leading zeros because its easier
void PrintNumberV3(int base, unsigned long long num )
{
    const static char toAscii[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    if ((base < 2) || (base>16))
    {
        Serial.print("[DON'T USE THAT BASE!!!]");
        return;
    }

    char buffer[65];            //because you might be doing binary
    char* p = &buffer[64];      //this pointer writes into the buffer, starting at the END

    // zero to terminate a C type string
    *p = 0;

    // do digits until the number reaches zero
    do
    {
        // working on the least significant digit
        //put an ASCII digit at the front of the string
        *(--p) = toAscii[(int)(num % base)];

        //knock the least significant digit off the number
        num = num / base;
    } while (num != 0);

    //print the whole string
    Serial.print(s);
}
```

Warning:  None of these have been tried on an actual Arduino

Comment: Thanks man, I'm trying... Good solution but this need a fix because i'm using streaming.h for serial output. Another problem is that it split the number in the wrong position. 100000 need to be changed in 1000000000L. So the formula for each buffer should be (uint32_t)(x/10000000000L) and (uint32_t)(x%10000000000L). char buffer is not needed. It can be outputted directly (at least with streaming.h module).  please can you change it? So i can use this as a solution. thanks

Comment: I do not have an arduino.  The character buffer is used with the sprintf call to give you the 'leading zero' characters on the string for the remainder part.  Without that, te two strings will not read together right when the least significant part drops leading zeros

Comment: as you mentioned in your edited answer, the billion division do not resolve completely my problem (thanks for raise this, 
I had not paid much attention), al least in theory isn't completly correct. But for some reason the output with this formula: MSBval = (uint32_t)(val / 10000000000LL); LSBval = (uint32_t)(val % 10000000000LL); Serial << MSBval << LSBval; give me the right results with 64bit higher numbers (like 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 [18446744073709551615] ). I'm trying to investigate on it and searching for a better solution. thanks

Comment: So modulus 10 billion.  let N = 18446744073709551615.  MS part is 1844674407, LS remainder is 3709551615, which can fit in 32 bits.  But recall there will be numbers where the remainder is greater than 4294967296.   For instance, try your program with 18440000009000000000LL and see how it works.

Comment: You may want to consider thinking smaller instead of larger.  Review the comment made by @chux on the question , and think about doing things mod 10.  10 is still a power of ten.

Comment: I'm going to try editing your question to see if they will take it off hold

Comment: I tested it and you have right. With 18440000009000000000LL it return a wrong number. I'm testing for other algorithms and check the answer that you suggest. Thank you for what you're doing.

Comment: Well, they took my edit of the question (they made some style changes).  But I don't know if you have to appeal somehow to get it off hold

Comment: @Tungsteno, sorry, got tired of waiting

Comment: oh, lol, we posted a solution at the same time! :D